# How can i display the column name of a table

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I use the following code to display a table.

```
final Vector<Vector<String>> vct = refreshDatas();
final Vector<String> Cols = new Vector<String>();
Cols.add("OID");
Cols.add("Name");
this.tmodel = new DefaultTableModel(vct,Cols);
this.table.setModel(this.tmodel);
this.table.setBounds(50, 200, 300, 250);
this.table.setSize(200, 200);
this.table.setVisible(true);
```

but only the contents is displayed. The header `OID` and `Name` are not displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add the table in to the JScrollPane, It automatically display the table headers.

Answer (score 2):

See the ['Adding a table to a container'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#show) section in the table tutorial.
If you add the table yourself, you must make the headers visible as well. If you add your table to a scrollpane, the scrollpane will take care of this for you.

Copy-paste from that tutorial:

> If you are using a table without a scroll pane, then you must get the table header component and place it yourself. For example:

```
container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
container.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
container.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Sidenote: it should not be needed to call `setBounds` nor `setSize`. Just make sure your parent `Container` has a decent `LayoutManager` and it will take care of the size

Comment: can i retrieve the values of the field OID and Name from the same table i specified abow? can you suggest any solution?

Comment: See `DefaultTableModel#getColumnName`